# Infinite union of interval

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

For each $n\in \Bbb{N}$, let $A_n=[0,n)$. Find

$\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb{N}}A_n$ .

**Attempt:** Let $x\in\bigcup [0,n)$. Then $x\in A_n$ for some $n\in\Bbb{N}$.Then $0\leq x<n.$
therefore, $x\in [0,\infty)$. Thus $\bigcup_{n\in \Bbb{N}}[0,n)\subset [0,\infty)$.

Let $x\in [0,\infty)$. Then $0\leq x<\infty$. As $\Bbb{N}$ is unbounded, $x<n$ for some $n\in\Bbb{N}$. Thus $x\in [0,n)$ for some $n\in\Bbb{N}$implies$ [0,\infty)\subset \bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}A_n$.

Hence $\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb{N}}A_n=[0,\infty)$.

Is it correct?

I already assumed answer. I need a way to do it without assuming the answer.

Comment: Show the reverse inclusion.

Comment: Is this inclusion correct?

Comment: I don't know which inclusion "this" is referring to, but both inclusions are correct.

Comment: I am asking which i proved above.

Comment: First of all, before you start writing symbols down: do you know the answer? Do you have an intuition?

Comment: @Jack M: Yes, As I can see as there are infinite union given. but anyway how to do without knowing answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first inclusion, you've proven $x\in [0,\infty)$ but that doesn't need the fact that $\mathbb{N}$ is unbounded. $x$ is in $[0,\infty)$ because all numbers in $A_n$ are nonnegative, for all $n$. Remember, $[0,\infty)$ can be written as the set of $x$ such that $x \geq 0$. So for that you don't need the unboundedness.

When you say "without loss of generality" in the second inclusion is exactly where you need to write "Due to $\mathbb{N}$ being unbounded", etc. Because it's there where you're using it.

Comment: I edited. But I already assumed the answer. How to solve without assuming the answer?

Comment: @Learner Now it's perfectly correct. What do you mean you "assumed the answer"? Usually one has some intuition behind what the union will be. In this case, it's clear if you write some examples that the union will be all nonnegative reals, as it turns out to be. Is that your question?

Comment: It's done! Thank you:)